# How can i modify Dijkstra algorithm for equal situation?

Tags: algorithms

I have a question below

In Dijkstra’s Algorithm, if there is more than one possible shortest path from u to any vertex v, any one of the paths can be the output of the algorithms as a shortest path.  Assume now that if that is the case for any vertex v, i.e.there are many paths of the same minimum weight, you want to find the path with minimum number of edges.  If there are stil ties then they can now be broken arbitrarily.  Describe how to modify Dijkstra’s Algorithm to solve this problem

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercise-style problems for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  We're not a homework help site and we're not looking for posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task and a demand for us to solve it for you.

Comment: Always credit the original source of all copied material.  Please [edit] your question to do so.

Comment: Well this is from question set from class how can i this credit? If you want i can delete this question and i will try to ask good questions.

Comment: The first thing is to not copy-paste, understand the question and write it in your own words. Next, you need to acknowledge that it is from the assignment, but you tried xyz methodology and are stuck at so and so place.
Finally, you need to accept an answer if its correct and useful.

Comment: Hint: modify the weights such that a path with less edges is strictly shorter than a path with more edges that had the same weight previously.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Multiply the original weights by a large constant $L$ so that new edge weights are scaled, and become greater than $n$.

Step 2: Add 1 to each edge weight.

Step 3: Run Dijkstra with new weights.

You can test and verify yourself on small examples that this will give the shortest path with minimum edges.